# sas - group by two diff columns

Tags: sas

I've the below dataset as input

### ID   category  cust.nr  cust.name  income

1    a        100   Crosbie        5000
2    a        200   Heier          5500
2    a        300   Pick           5500
3    a        400   Sandridge      5100
4    b        500   Groesbeck      10000
4    b        600   Hayton         11000
4    b        700   Razor          12000
5    c        800   Lamere         90000

I need a report (f.ex using proc tabulate) as follows

In the data, cust.nr are unique but all the customers belonging to one family are given same ID, and customers are categorized based on their income.
<10000 as a
10000 to 15000 as b
'>'15000 as c

I need a report with

count of unique IDs(families), grouped by categories, and also rest of the columns need to be shown in the report.

so, it should look like

count_ID   category cust.nr  cust.name  income

--------    ------   100   Crosbie        5000
 --------    ------   200   Heier          5500
3              a      300   Pick           5500
 --------    ------   400   Sandridge      5100

--------    ------   500   Groesbeck      10000
1              b      600   Hayton         11000
 --------    -------- 700   Razor          12000

1               c     800   Lamere         90000

Any suggestions please..

Comment: Your question is far too vague to even attempt an answer. I see no connection between the first dataset and the second. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with `proc sql`:

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table results as
  select category,
         count(distinct id) as count_id
  from mytable
  group by 1
  ;
quit;
```